# Quick Settings enable/disable each setting/icon on lock screen

Tags: lock-screens, quick-settings, gravitybox

I noted on one of my phones in Quick Settings (dropdown) e.g. Wi-Fi icon is enabled on lock screen, on other phone it is asking for screen-pattern. So I want a way to customize this. I've read that article [How to Tweak and Rearrange Android’s Quick Settings Drop down-bar](https://www.howtogeek.com/231078/use-android-6.0%E2%80%99s-hidden-system-ui-tuner-to-customize-your-quick-settings-and-status) Then tried to find out if at least on rooted phones GravityBox app has this tweak but could not find info, only links where all menu is enabled/disabled. Is there a way to set for each icon/setting to be enabled/disabled on locked screen?

Added: by disabling I mean phone allows to use setting w/out unlocking the screen. The setting icon may be present on locked screen, but require unlocking when tapped. Other way setting is visible on unlocked phone but hidden on locked screen. Enabling is the opposite. E.g. many phones from stock setup allow flashlight to be activated on locked screen, but do not allow mobile data connection to be turned on/off. I'm looking for ways to change it - e.g. disable flashlight, enable mobile data connection on/off from locked screen via quick settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm looking for ways to change it - e.g. disable flashlight, enable mobile data connection on/off from locked screen via quick settings.

Yes, GravityBox can let you do that. See screen shot below

[image]

Take Wi-Fi  for instance. If configured as shown, from quick settings via lockscreen, one **cannot** enable Wi-Fi. Because tick means *protected while screen is locked*

However, if you do not tick the Wi-Fi box, you can enable it from quick settings in lock screen mode without entering password.

In addition, some GravityBox specific
tweaks like NFC (not stock NFC), Ringer mode, volume, network mode, smart radio, sync, Torch (of GravityBox), sleep, stay awake, quick apps and many more can be be configured to be added to quick settings and managed as described.

Edit: More features that can be added to Quick settings below (in addition to the ones listed). If you tick the second box on right against the feature (currently greyed out), they cannot be enabled from lock screen.

[image]

Comment: This is on Android 11. I have been using Gravity Box since Android 4.2 and AFAIR, these features were there in all versions, with minor additions /deletions

Comment: Thank you. I wonder which smartphone manufacturers allow this functionality w/out root.

Comment: On second thoughts, OEMs may NOT like to add this feature. For instance, you've forgotten your PIN or lost your phone. Google find can't trace your phone without data and if you've locked it this way, what do you do? I don't think this is a feature for ordinary folks